# select entry from database based on parameter php pdo

Tags: php, html, pdo

it is hard for me to explain the question so i will just state a scenario:

in my database the entry saved are `door,do,dont,deed,did,doo` and i type `do` in the search box to be used as parameter to search database so now the parameter i used for search is `do`.

`1.the question is, is it possible to search all the entries with the letter *do* in them i mean in my example the words *door,do,dont,doo* should be selected.`

`2.how can i do this kind of search`

any suggestion is appreciated

***UPDATE:***

something like an autocomplete select

Comment: I think you should read your database documentation or a beginners guide to SQL. You will be surprised how easy the answer to this question would be after doing the most basic research yourself. Hint "like"

Comment: may i just ask what kind of search is like this so i can find or search for it..

Comment: see the answers some kind people have given you below. But I think there kindness is misplaced, you need to learn the tools you are using, and, at least learn how to search a manual. Embarking on a database project with no knowledge of basic SQL is going to be a painful experience.

Comment: still thank you for your response

Comment: Any reason why your questions must be in inline code boxes rather than displayed as a list? (Revision of edit)

Comment: it is much easier to read this way and easy to understand since i cant fully explain what im trying to achieve here the best i can do is to clearly show the scenario by doing it this way..any reason why i cant do it this way or any restrictions doing it this way?

Comment: @satinekianne Don't think so, it just looks like a post that is usually made by people who are unfamiliar with Markdown. But that might just be me; I was just curious to know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes you can: SQL:

   ```
       SELECT * FROM yourTableName where yourFieldName like 'do%'
   ```
2. I guess you want to implement a autosuggestion. If this is the case than use jQuery to make Ajax calls to your Server. The script on the server gets the request with the letters in the searchbox, here 'do', excutes the SQL from 1. (you have to adapt with the letters you get) and response it to the website with the possible words, here door, do, dont... . Than the jQuery gets the response and builds from the possible words a list and displays it.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: yes you get what im trying here let me just try the suggestion for it may take me sometime because im new here but i will definately be back on you on this

Comment: Try this http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ for the autocomplete than and this http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

A simple like query should do job

```
select * from 'your table name' where 'column_name' like %do%
```

[For More info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

And You should really really read documentations more clearly.(just an advice)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LIKE clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) to perform this.

For example:

```
 SELECT column FROM table WHERE column LIKE do%
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **LIKE** operator in where condition of you query